# boost iostream performance degradation when add more filter to stream

Tags: c++, boost

The task I need to accomplish is simple: "ungzip an inputstream and count how many characters were produced".

c++ code:

```cpp
this->inflateOut = std::make_unique<boost::iostreams::filtering_ostream>();
this->inflateOut->push(zlibDecompressor, 32768);
this->inflateOut->push(boost::ref(counter), 32768);
this->inflateOut->push(out, 32768);
```

java code:

```java
this.out = new CountingOutputStream(out);
uncompressor = new DeflateUncompressor();
uncompressor.setNowrap(mode == Mode.UNCOMPRESS_NOWRAP);
uncompressor.uncompress(in, out);
```

I did a test myself, with the same inputStream, java version of code took 13s while cpp version of code took 33s. If I removed `this->inflateOut->push(boost::ref(counter), 32768);` the time cpp code consumes will drop to 23s.

I read the boost code and I think it's because instead of being a simple wrapper around dest outputStream, boost filters are independent components which has their own buffer (which is also very annoying when setting up, it's quite easy to forget to set bufferSize).

In short, java iostream is using a decorator pattern and boost iostream is more like "chain of responsibility" pattern (or more precisely `filter pattern`).

Is there an alternative way to do this in cpp (maybe with boost)?

### Edit:

After changing build type to release, the time it consumes drops to 22s (still slower than java), and removing counter will further decreasing time to 19s.
My compiler flags are `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE: /MD /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG`, I am compiling this with vs toolchain.

Comment: platform, compiler, compilation flags?

Comment: @MarekR windows VS toolchain debug build, I didn't think compiler could make such a big difference.

Comment: @MarekR After changing build type, it surely speed up a lot. But not enough...